# Question: heat equation for the laser-drilling equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I thought equation below can be solved using fourier transform but I could not apply the boundary conditions. Is there anybody who can solve this equation?

∂²U/∂ε²  +  ∂U/∂ε  +  ∂U/∂T =0

where U(ε,T) is (dimensionless) temperature T and ε dimensionless is boundary position respectively.

The boundary conditions are:

u(ε,0) = 0,     ε > 0
u(0,T) = 1,     T ≥ 0
u(∞,T) =0,      T ≥ 0

Comment: What is the question here? To solve the PDE?

Comment: Do you really need to solve this classically ill-posed problem? Google indicates that its formulation  is copy-pasted from http://nmcabuja.org/proceedings/workshop_Oyelami_Asere.pdf, where the function claimed to be a solution, in fact, does not solve this problem, solution of which cannot exist in any known weakest sense.

Comment: @mkl314, please expand to an answer (or, if short of time, give hints so someone else can fill in the details)

Comment: @vonbrand: Expanded to an answer and posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to see why the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{xx}+u_x+u_t=0, \quad x>0,\;t>0,\\
u|_{t=0}=0,\quad x>0,\\
u|_{x=0}=1,\quad t>0,\\
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}u(x,t)=0, \quad t>0,
\end{cases}\tag{1}
$$ 
cannot be solved. Indeed, let a weak solution to problem $(1)$ exist in $Q_{\tau}=(0,\infty)\times (0,\tau)$ for some $\tau>0$. Even if it be a weak solution of the class $L^2(Q_{\tau})$, solution $u\in C^{\infty}(Q_{\tau})$ while $u(\cdot,s)\in C[0,\infty)$ and $u(x,s)\to 0\,$ as $\,x\to\infty$ with any fixed $s\in (0,\tau)$. Solving problem  $(1)$, well-posed backwards with the initial data $u|_{t=s}=u(\cdot,s)$, one gets a classical backward solution 
$$
u\in C^{\infty}\bigl((0,\infty)\times (-\delta,s)\bigr)\cap C\bigl ([0,\infty)\times (-\delta,s]\bigr),\quad \delta>0.
$$
The latter must coincide with the original solution to $(1)$, while the backward solution is continuous at the origin and $u(0,0)=1$, which is in contradiction with the original initial condition 
$$
u|_{t=0}=0, \quad t>0
$$ 
in $(1)$, and which implies that problem $(1)$ cannot possess even a weak solution.

But there is no need in solving the ill-posed problem $(1)$. Google indicates that its formulation is copy-pasted from the paper http://nmcabuja.org/proceedings/workshop_Oyelami_Asere.pdf that is unbelievably bad-written, with its wrong citations and wrong references turning a *well-posed laser-drilling problem* to the ill-posed nonsense $(1)$.  The unperturbed original source for $(1)$ is:
http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/MIRROR/zmath/en/advanced/?q=an:00762217&type=pdf&format=complete
with further references therein. A detailed introduction into a *laser-drilling equation* can be found in Ch. 4 of *"Industrial Mathematics. Case Studies in the Diffusion of Heat and Matter"* by Glenn Fulford and Philip Broadbridge.

Answer (score 0):

The semi-infinite domain is different between the Cauchy problem.

[Semi-infinite heat/diffusion equation with time-dependent B.C. at x=0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434552/semi-infinite-heat-diffusion-equation-with-time-dependent-b-c-at-x-0)

It might have the same question with you.